# populating values in table in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

hi i have given the following code as

```
if (beiiInpTable_id != "") {
    var k = beiiInpTable_id;
    console.log($('#' + k + ' .name'));
    $('#' + k + '.name').html(beiiinpName);
    $('#' + k + '.type').html(beiiinpDataType);
    $('#' + k + '.alias').html(beiiinpAlias);
    $('#' + k + '.value').html(beiiinpDefault);

}
```

this code has been given in pagebeforeshow, there are values in the variables but they are not getting populated in the table. Before it worked but now it is not working, can someone help me please thanks

Comment: Show your DOM structure

Answer (score 0):

I think `name, type, alias, value` are children of `beiiInpTable_id`, so you have to give space for b/w id and class

```
if (beiiInpTable_id != "") {
    var k = beiiInpTable_id;
    console.log($('#' + k + ' .name'));
    $('#' + k + ' .name').html(beiiinpName);
    $('#' + k + ' .type').html(beiiinpDataType);
    $('#' + k + ' .alias').html(beiiinpAlias);
    $('#' + k + ' .value').html(beiiinpDefault);
                ^^ space need for children selector 


}
```

NOTE:`$('#' + k + '.name'), $('#' + k + '.type'),$('#' + k + '.alias'),$('#' + k + '.value')` it is all point out `only one element not 4` ,so may be that is all children of id

Comment: @keerthanaalivelu show your code in fiddle or ,dom structure

Comment: @keerthanaalivelu  what it is printed in log console.log($('#' + k + ' .name'));

Comment: @keerthanaalivelu Or make sample and show in fiddle ,otherwise we can not solve ur issue

Comment: Object[]
  
 
context
 Document BEIIinpGrid.html
 
jquery
 "1.10.2"
 
length
 0
 
prevObject
 Object[Document BEIIinpGrid.html]
 
selector
 "#1 .name"

Comment: @keerthanaalivelu As you saying   $'#' + k + ' .name') length 0,That means There is no element of that name ,so you have to show some sample dom structure and what it will return beiiInpTable_id

Comment: @keerthanaalivelu see this sample  http://jsfiddle.net/btxc7ymz/1/,so all elements are children of id , i think the issue is return value beiiInpTable_id

Comment: in js i have given directly given string but still it is not working

Comment: yes bala in selector it is showing in that way only

Comment: @keerthanaalivelu test in console console.log(beiiInpTable_id); , what it is print

Comment: @keerthanaalivelu Then my code should be work ..replace my code

Comment: one doubt but why the code in  jsfiddle.net/btxc7ymz/2 not working

Comment: @keerthanaalivelu it is working in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Q3Usv/486/ ,but we have to include in mobile js in head

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>   these are the jquery  used